# Increment a byte[]

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `byte[] testKey = new byte[8];`

This obviously starts with all bytes as 0.  I want to go through all the bytes and increment by 1 on each iteration of the loop so eventually I go through all possibilities of the byte array.  I also want to do this as FAST as possible.  Yes I am trying to write a brute forcer.

**Update**  I got the unsafe method working, and it is the quickest.  However, by my calculations, it is going to take 76,000,000 years to loop through doing DES encryption on each key using the .Net DESCryptoServiceProvider.  10,000 encryptions takes 1.3 seconds.  Thanks for all the awesome answers to the most useless question ever!

Comment: To test all 2^64 combinations will take a very long time.

Comment: It will take about seven years just to loop throught the combinations, considerably more if you actually do something with each combination. Brute force doesn't seem to be the correct approach for this...

Comment: Yeah, unless you have the computing resources of a government agency or huge corporation behind you, you have no chance of exhaustively testing a search space of size 2^64.  Even if each test took only a single cycle to run on a modern CPU, it would take 71 thousand years to finish testing the entire search space.

Comment: @stephentyrone: How did you come up with the figure 71000 years? 2^64/3E9/3600/24/365 ~ 195 years.

Comment: sorry, meant 71 thousand days =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

btw; it takes a *lot* of processing to check 2^64 options...

Well, the *fastest* way may be to just use an `Int64` (aka `long`) or `UInt64` (`ulong`), and use `++`? Do you really need the `byte[]`?

As a hacky alternative, how about:

```
Array.Clear(data, 0, data.Length);
while (true)
{
  // use data here
  if (++data[7] == 0) if (++data[6] == 0)
    if (++data[5] == 0) if (++data[4] == 0)
      if (++data[3] == 0) if (++data[2] == 0)
        if (++data[1] == 0) if (++data[0] == 0) break;
}
```

The only other approach I can think of would be to use unsafe code to talk to an array *as though* it is an int64... messy.

```
unsafe static void Test() {
    byte[] data = new byte[8];
    fixed (byte* first = data) {
        ulong* value = (ulong*)first;
        do {
            // use data here
            *value = *value + 1;
        } while (*value != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the overhead of fixing the array in memory to use it in unsafe code would outweigh the benefit of being able to treat it as an int64...

Comment: You should use ulong* in the unsafe code, not uint*. Eventhough you loop inside the fixed statement, it's surprisingly slow. My managed code to increase the array is about 200 times faster...

Answer (score 7):

This is how you increase the value in the array:

```
int index = testKey.Length - 1;
while (index >= 0) {
   if (testKey[index] < 255) {
      testKey[index]++;
      break;
   } else {
      testKey[index--] = 0;
   }
}
```

When `index` is -1 after this code, you have iterated all combinations.

This will be slightly faster than using BitConverter, as it doesn't create a new array for each iteration.

Edit:
A small performance test showed that this is about 1400 times faster than using BitConverter...

Comment: I upvoted because I see potential here.  The problem is that the `break` statement is in the wrong place.  As-is the code won't go past 1.

Comment: @makerofthings7: Thanks for the upvote. I think that you misunderstand the code. It will increase the array by one. To increase it another step, you use the code again. If you want to use it in a loop, you put the code in the loop.

Comment: Wow that's fast!  I got to 1 Billion in 4.2 seconds!

Comment: Though @Marc's unsafe code above clocked in at 2.7 seconds for the same iteration count.

Answer (score 4):

What a great question!  Here's a way to do it without unsafe code:

```
public struct LongAndBytes
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public ulong UlongValue;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Byte0;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte Byte1;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte Byte2;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte Byte3;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public byte Byte4;
    [FieldOffset(5)]
    public byte Byte5;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public byte Byte6;
    [FieldOffset(7)]
    public byte Byte7;

    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        return new byte[8] {Byte0, Byte1, Byte2, Byte3, Byte4, Byte5, Byte6, Byte7};
    }
}


// ...

    LongAndBytes lab = new LongAndBytes();

    lab.UlongValue = 0;
    do {
        // stuff
        lab.UlongValue++;
    } while (lab.ULongValue != 0);
```

Each of the members Byte0...Byte7 overlap the ulong and share its members.  It's not an array - I tried dinking around with that and had unsatisfactory results.  I bet someone knows the magic declaration to make that happen.  I can do that for a P/Invoke, but not for use in .NET as an array is an object.

Comment: `byte[] b = new byte[8] {Byte0, Byte1, Byte2, Byte3, Byte4, Byte5, Byte6, Byte7};`

Comment: +1 for awesomeness.. I love this answer, simple yet powerful.

Comment: The for loop will miss the last combination. You need a different loop where you check after incrementing the value if it has reached zero again.

Answer (score 3):

byte[8] is essentially an ulong but if you really need it to be byte[8] you can use

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
ulong i = 0;
bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the bytes using bit operators:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
for (ulong u = 0; u < ulong.MaxValue; u++)
{
    bytes[0] = (byte)(u & 0xff);
    bytes[1] = (byte)((u >> 8) & 0xff);
    bytes[2] = (byte)((u >> 16) & 0xff);
    bytes[3] = (byte)((u >> 24) & 0xff);
    bytes[4] = (byte)((u >> 32) & 0xff);
    bytes[5] = (byte)((u >> 40) & 0xff);
    bytes[6] = (byte)((u >> 48) & 0xff);
    bytes[7] = (byte)((u >> 56) & 0xff);
    // do your stuff...
}
```

This is less 'hackish', since it operates on an unsigned 64-bit integer first and then extract the bytes. However beware CPU endianess.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UInt64 i = 0; i < UInt64.MaxValue; i++)
{
    byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(i)
}
```

Comment: This creates a new `byte[]` per call, making lots of work for allocation and garbage collection; there are faster ways using a fixed array

Comment: This loop will either be done in no time or in the spring of year 7854.

Comment: Just looping through the combinations will take about seven years using the faster method in my answer. Using BitConverter it will take about 10000 years...

Comment: To be finished in 7 years you need to process 2^64/(7*365.25*24*3600*1000) = 83506006 per millisecond. Really?

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] array = new byte[8];
int[] shifts = new int[] { 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56 };    
for (long index = long.MinValue; index <= long.MaxValue; index++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (byte)((index >> shifts[i]) & 0xff);
    }
    // test array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length & 0 == ++bytes[i]; i++);
```

Should be as fast as the unsafe method and allows arrays of any size.

Comment: Probably the best answer. No hacks, simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Simple iteration:

```
static IEnumerable<byte[]> Iterate(int arrayLength) {
    var arr = new byte[arrayLength];
    var i = 0;
    yield return arr;
    while (i < arrayLength)
    {
        if (++arr[i] != 0)
        {
            i = 0;
            yield return arr;
        }
        else i++;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var arr in Iterate(2))
    {
        Console.Write(String.Join(",", arr.Select(x => $"{x:D3}")));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late post, but I needed the described feature too and implemented it in a pretty easy way in my opinion. Maybe it's useful for somebody else too:

```
private byte[] IncrementBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    for (var i = bytes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (bytes[i] < byte.MaxValue)
        {
            bytes[i]++;
            break;
        }
        bytes[i] = 0;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

BitConverter.ToInt64 / BitConverter.GetBytes - convert 8 byte to exactly long, and increment it.
When almost done convert back to bytes.
It is the fastest way in system

Comment: `BitConverter`? fastest? Creating a new `byte[]` **per call** is **not** the fastest by any stretch.

Comment: Idea was to make some logical brackets - start you convert (ONCE!) bytes to long. Multiple times increase as many as you can, at the end (WHEN ALMOST DONE and ONCE!) convert back to bytes